# Draw an opaque circle (with some text) on a tikz line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code right now -

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (1.5,0) circle (5pt) node{a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If we see the output, the circle has the line inside it which I don't want. Also I don't want to draw the line in two parts (i.e.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1.3,0);
\draw (1.7,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (1.5,0) circle (5pt) node{a};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

)

This code gives me the output exactly like I want, but I don't want to do that calculation manually and draw so many lines in my entire picture. How to have a circle which is opaque, but also with some text?

Comment: You could just fill it white, `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\path (1.5,0) node[circle,minimum size=10pt,fill=white,draw]{a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force way is to fill the circle white. To shorten the code, the circle is drawn as a node and put on the middle of the path.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node[circle,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,draw]{a} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to overpaint anything in white, you can still do it in one path,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) -- node[circle,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt,draw](a){a} (3,0)
(a) edge (0,0)  edge  (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the function of `inner sep=0pt`? It's actually making my circle smaller

Comment: @Niranjan If you add `\draw [dashed,red] (1.5,0) circle[radius=5pt];` to the code before `\end{tikzpicture}` you see that the radii of the black and red dashed circles are the same. `inner sep` prevents the node from getting too large (in this case).

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)     node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {tight}
        (0cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {loose}
        (0cm,4em) node[fill=examplefill]   {default};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 1):

Drawing line in two parts not need manual calculation of their inner coordinates, however drawings of more lines can't be avoided:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) -- node (n) [circle,draw,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt] {a} (3,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (n)  (n) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]